# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Django Project Health Check Fails

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a Django application to Elastic Beanstalk, in single instance type there is no problem and the health check is green, but when I choose the Load Balanced type and add HTTPs listener with a valid certificate from Amazon Certificate Manager,the health became Severe and also when I click on view causes it show me this (Process default has been unhealthy for 15 hours (Target.FailedHealthChecks)), I can access the website with the HTTPs and also HTTP, there is no problem, all settings are correct, I have the security group with inbound and outbound rules, but the health became severe.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to check Target Group, Health Check Configuration, Security Group Configuration, SSL Certificate, SSL Certificate also examine the detailed logs and metrics for your load balancer.

Comment: There is one EC2 instance in the target group and the health is unhealthy, and the details is (Health checks failed with these codes: [400])

Comment: Check the health check settings on your Elastic Beanstalk environment. Ensure that the path and port specified in the health check match your Django application's configuration. Review the ELB access logs for more details on the 400 error.